# calling a http get request in java

Tags: java

I want the request of http get request using the following java code.
But, uncertainly i am getting the following exception.

```
    import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class API {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
        URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

The Error or exception is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:213)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1296)
    at API.main(API.java:8)
```

Comment: Are you sure throwing exceptions? I have tried above function.It working fine for me.

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a firewall and it's blocking this HTTP get request.

You code should work as you expect it. Something outside the Java runtime is preventing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you can ping to `http://www.oracle.com/`.

If you can ping check whether you are behind a proxy server.

If so provide `-Dhttp.proxyHost` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort` while starting the JVM

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=<Your Proxy Server Name/IP> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<Your Proxy Server Port>
```

Comment: Yes, i can ping http://www.oracle.com/...how to provide -Dhttp.proxyHost and -Dhttp.proxyPort while starting the JVM???

Comment: JVM's allow you to define system properties from the command line. You can perform this by using the `-D` argument, in the form `-Dproperty=value`